# Можно ли ускорить sql запрос?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine2, symfony5

В doctrine:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder()
     ->where('field IN (array)')
     ->setParameter('array', $array)
     ->andWhere('param = :param')
     ->setParameter('param', bool)
     ->select('field')
     ->getQuery()
     ->getResult();
```

один параметр boolean, второй массив, в массиве может быть много значений (от 100 тыс)

Comment: можно. ускорить можно любой запрос.

Comment: Хотите ускорить? Во-первых, нафиг фреймворки, только нативный SQL. Во-вторых - текст запроса точно в том виде, в каком он отправляется на MySQL, точный CREATE TABLE таблицы, пример данных таблицы (не менее 5 записей в форме INSERT INTO), статистику таблицы, общую и по каждому условию отбора, а также точную версию MySQL - в студию.

Comment: от 100тыс значений в параметр?

Comment: @Ипатьев `select 1;` ? )

Comment: @teran да легко. посмотреть где лежит сервер БД и сколько до него хопов.

Comment: @Akina наверняка там не сам запрос, а либо гидрация, либо  пагинация. Ну то есть та часть, которая " нафиг фреймворки". Пагинация в доктрине сделана через одно место, а точнее путем выборки всех айдишников. Ну и гидрация 100 тыщ объектов, если там выборка без лимита - это смерть.

Answer (score 0):

Желательно видеть полную структуру таблицы в БД.
Запрос может тормозить из-за отсутствия индекса на поле `field` и `param`.
Массив значений в любом случае желательно уменьшить до 500-1000 через чанкование:

```php
$chunks = array_chunk($array, 500);

foreach ($chunk as $chunks) {
    $this->createQueryBuilder()
        ->where('field IN (array)')
        ->setParameter('array', $chunk)
        ->andWhere('param = :param')
        ->setParameter('param', bool)
        ->select('field')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    // Результат собираем в общий массив
}
```

Если нужно еще больше ускорить запросы, тогда есть смысл использоать нативные SQL запросы минуя доктрину.